# Problemas con getter de una variable estática.

Tags: java

Como he dicho en el titulo, tengo problemas con la función `get` , esta es mi clase con la variable a `setear`:

```
package Modelo;

public class Control {

public static String variable;

public String getVariable() {
    return variable;
}

public void setVariable(String variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
}
}
```

Esta es mi clase donde tengo un `JTextField` y un `JButton` para capturar el texto:

```
package Vista;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     Control c = new Control();
     Main m = new Main();
     String variable="";
        variable = jTextField1.getText();
        c.setVariable(variable);
        m.setVisible(true);
 }
```

El asunto es que tengo una tercera clase `JFrame` donde existe un `JLabel`

```
Control c = new Control();
jLabe1.setText(c.getVariable());
```

Hice un seguimiento de donde se perdía el contenido de la variable y el resultado fue que se perdía en el `get` ya que dentro de la clase set se puede imprimir el valor de la variable y aun es correcto pero en el método `get` la variable el **null.**

Comment: Sin ver el código completo, tu variable `Control c` es local a la función `jButton1ActionPerformed`, por lo que cuando finaliza esta última el valor desaparece junto con la variable.

Comment: No se como siquiera te compilo. `variable` esta marcada como `static` por lo que `this.variable = variable`  lanzaria un error debido a que `variable` no pernece a la instancia de la clase.

Comment: @Einer Eso lanza un warning, puedes acceder a los atributos estáticos con this pero no es recomendado

Comment: @DavidIsla @Einer aun que moví el `Control c` hacia fuera y le quité el  
`static` a la variable, aun no funciona

Comment: @Sodro fuera o dentro no tiene nada que ver a menos que quiera trabajar con una variable a nivel de clase, ahí si sería necesario declararla fuera de los métodos y listeners. Lo de quitar el `static` es lo correcto. Revisó mi respuesta?

Comment: @Sodro sería posible que al estar en diferentes paquetes no lo hayas importado correctamente?

Comment: @DavidDPG no creo, hago el importe automatico `import Modelo.Control`

Comment: @Sodro aún persiste el problema ? ¿ Tomo en cuenta mi respuesta?

Comment: @Dev.Joel aun tengo el problema , de hecho, tuve que avanzar dejando el MVC de lado y pasar los datos de forma directa

Comment: @Sodro qué problemas presenta ?  mi respuesta no solucionó el problema ? según como está su pregunta debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

El error es normal, esto es porque el valor por `default` de un `String` no inicializado es `null` por eso cuando hace  `Control c = new Control();` creó el objeto con su atributo variable en null y al intentar asignar al `jLabel` arroja el error .

Otra cuestión es que no veo la necesidad de crear `getters` y `setters` para una variable estática . ya que podría acceder a ella sin crear la instancia de la clase. es decir para acceder bastaría con   `Control.variable;`.

Lo correcto sería tener la variable como privada y tener sus `getters` y `setters` ,además quizá crear el constructor sin parámetros para inicializar la variable.

```
public class Control {

    private  String variable;
    public Control() {
        this.variable = "";// Inicializar la variable
    }

    public String getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }
    public void setVariable(String variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
}
```

y en JFrame

```
Control c = new Control(); // se crea la instancia con el valor de variable =""
// Aquí falta llamar al setter de la variable como lo hace en action del botón
//si no solo mostrará vacío el label como se especifico en el constructor
jLabe1.setText(c.getVariable());
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu variable es static y public para que haces un método set? recuerda que las variables estaticas son de clase no de instancia por lo que no deberias usarla con el keyword this. Las variables de clase se acceden a travez del nombre de la clase mas el operador `.` mas el nombre de la variable. Aunque también se pueden usar con tu la estas usando a través de la instancia no es lo recomendado estas gastando memoria innecesariamente y cualquier IDE decente te marcaria un warning.

Ten siempre en mente que cuando usas static estas usando un antipatron. static es muy usado en clases utilitarias que no necesitan valores diferentes por instancia.

```
package Modelo;

public class Control {

    public static String variable;
}
```

--

```
    package Vista;

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             Main m = new Main();
         Control.variable = jTextField1.getText();
         m.setVisible(true);
    }
```

--

```
jLabe1.setText(Control.getVariable());
```